# Rewrite URL with .htaccess passing multiple parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

This type of question is already asked before but I cannot find specific solution. I've trying this for last few hours and if anyone could help me it would be really helpful.

I am developing an Ecommerce site and I have this url

http://localhost/ecommerce/product?torzoProName=Samsung%20Series%204&torzoProId=17&torzoProRef=7762fe27ee4b92d_1563945302&torzoProSeller=219

I want it to look like

http://localhost/ecommerce/product/Samsung-Series-4/pid=17&pref=7762fe27ee4b92d_1563945302&psid=219

I've tried something but it seems not to work at all.

```
#.htaccess codes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#replace cart.php page with cart
RewriteRule ^cart$ view_cart.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^wishlist$ view_wishlist.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product.php?torzoProName=$1&torzoProId=$2&torzoProRef=$3&torzoProSeller=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ product.php?torzoProName=$1&torzoProId=$2&torzoProRef=$3&torzoProSeller=$4 [NC,L]
```

I get this Error in chrome

> (500 Internal Error)
>
> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: First of all I suggest you to try one rule at time to see which one throws an error

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work, can't figure out where I did wrong. I'll try it again. Thanks.

Comment: Not a rewrite expert here but as far as I can see `product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)` contains four slashes (`/`) whereas your desired url only has two. Have you tried something like `/product/Samsung-Series-4/17/7762fe27ee4b92d_1563945302/219` in your browser?

Comment: The first thing you _always_ do on a 500 internal server error, is you go check the error logs.

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks for noticing. I tried updating my code but still not working.